# What is the quickest, simplest way to lauch a pre-existing restart?

Tags: error-handling, common-lisp

Ok, I need to rewrite this question.

If I go:

```
CL-USER> whatever
```

I get this in the debugger frame:

```
The variable WHATEVER is unbound.
   [Condition of type UNBOUND-VARIABLE]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 2: [TERMINATE-THREAD] Terminate this thread (#<THREAD "repl-thread" RUNNING {C0C6CF9}>)
 ...
```

Therefore, I should be able to do this:

```
(handler-case
    whatever
  (unbound-variable (e) (invoke-restart 'retry)))
```

Yet it yields:

```
No restart RETRY is active.
   [Condition of type SB-INT:SIMPLE-CONTROL-ERROR]
...
```

What am I missing?

The ABORT retry does work correctly; thanks hans and Svante for pointing that out. The others - retry, terminate-thread, etc - all error out.

I've also tried hitting e in the debugger and running INVOKE-RESTART directly. Same result with one exception: the low-level example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15473880/1435206) works like I think it should:

```
Eval in frame (COMMON-LISP-USER)> (invoke-restart 'go-on)
```

returns to the prompt without complaint. The high-level example will only restart correctly when selected by hand from the restarts menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `compute-restarts`, you will see that the restart `retry` is actually internal to the `swank` package:

```
(#<RESTART SWANK::RETRY {100462AE63}> #<RESTART ABORT {1003E4C2B3}>
 #<RESTART ABORT {1007138083}>)
```

If you qualify it thus as `swank::retry`, you get the expected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. That does the trick. Guess that infinite loop shouldn't have caught me by suprise. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The star in front of the restart 1 in your output indicates that this restart will be invoked by SLIME's [q]uit command.  The name of the restart is 'ABORT, so in order to invoke it, use this:

```
(handler-case
    whatever
  (unbound-variable (e) (invoke-restart 'abort)))
```

Comment: That works for you? It gives me  Evaluation aborted on #<SIMPLE-WARNING "undefined ~(~A~): ~S" {AE0F601}>.

Comment: I'm getting that same "No restart <x> is active" over a range of restarts and errors, for example, the USE-OLD restart from clsql:connect does the same thing.

Comment: That "Evaluation aborted..." message is exactly what the `abort` restart does.

Comment: @Svante - Ah, I see. If I replace 'abort with 'terminate-thread or 'retry, I get the no restart active message. Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

`retry` just tries again to evaluate the same variable. Since you did not bind it, it is still unbound. You might have better luck with

```
(handler-case
    whatever
  (unbound-variable (e)
    (setq whatever 42)
    (invoke-restart 'swank::retry)))
```

which should return 42.

Answer (score 2):

To see all the restarts and to get the actual symbols, so the following. Note that the debugger is not called and thus its restart(s) are not available.

```
CL-USER> (handler-case whatever
           (unbound-variable (c)
              (mapcar (lambda (r) (describe r) (terpri))
                      (compute-restarts c))
              (abort)))
```

We get:

```
#<RESTART SWANK::RETRY {10055BDB83}>                                                                                                                                                             
  [structure-object]                                                                                                                                                                             

Slots with :INSTANCE allocation:                                                                                                                                                                 
  NAME                  = SWANK::RETRY                                                                                                                                                           
  FUNCTION              = #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (&REST SB-IMPL::TEMP)..                                                                                                                              
  REPORT-FUNCTION       = #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (STREAM) :IN SWANK::CALL-WITH-RETRY-RESTART) {10055B..                                                                                               
  INTERACTIVE-FUNCTION  = NIL                                                                                                                                                                    
  TEST-FUNCTION         = #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (COND)..                                                                                                                                            



#<RESTART ABORT {10055B9A83}>                                                                                                                                                                    
  [structure-object]                                                                                                                                                                             

Slots with :INSTANCE allocation:                                                                                                                                                                 
  NAME                  = ABORT                                                                                                                                                                  
  FUNCTION              = #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (&REST SB-IMPL::TEMP) :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS) {1..                                                                                               
  REPORT-FUNCTION       = #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (STREAM) :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS) {10041ECF6B}>                                                                                                  
  INTERACTIVE-FUNCTION  = NIL                                                                                                                                                                    
  TEST-FUNCTION         = #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (COND)..                                                                                                                                            



#<RESTART SB-SYS:REMOVE-FD-HANDLER {10055B97D3}>                                                                                                                                                 
  [structure-object]                                                                                                                                                                             

Slots with :INSTANCE allocation:                                                                                                                                                                 
  NAME                  = SB-SYS:REMOVE-FD-HANDLER                                                                                                                                               
  FUNCTION              = #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (&REST SB-IMPL::TEMP)..                                                                                                                              
  REPORT-FUNCTION       = #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (STREAM) :IN SB-IMPL::SUB-SUB-SERVE-EVENT) {10055B97..                                                                                               
  INTERACTIVE-FUNCTION  = NIL                                                                                                                                                                    
  TEST-FUNCTION         = #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (COND)..                                                                                                                                            




#<RESTART ABORT {10029531B3}>                                                                                                                                                                    
  [structure-object]                                                                                                                                                                             

Slots with :INSTANCE allocation:                                                                                                                                                                 
  NAME                  = ABORT                                                                                                                                                                  
  FUNCTION              = #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (&REST SB-IMPL::TEMP) :IN SB-IMPL::TOPLEVEL-REPL) {1..                                                                                               
  REPORT-FUNCTION       = #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (STREAM) :IN SB-IMPL::TOPLEVEL-REPL) {100014A8BB}>                                                                                                  
  INTERACTIVE-FUNCTION  = NIL                                                                                                                                                                    
  TEST-FUNCTION         = #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (COND)..
```

Comment: (handler-case whatever (error (e) (compute-restarts e))) ; is more concise